# How to get all instances across regions with Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

is it possible to get a List with all instances (stopped and running) from all regions? I tried the following but got not all instances (just 4):

```
 DescribeInstancesResult describeInstances = ec2Client.describeInstances();
        List<Reservation> reservations = describeInstances.getReservations();

        for (Reservation reservation : reservations) {
            List<Instance> instances = reservation.getInstances();
             for (Instance instance : instances) {
                 System.out.println(instance.getInstanceId())
             }
        }
```

I think the instances I got were those I created with my account. Some of them were created before my account existed.

PS: My account has root rights so that should be no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
for (Regions region : Regions.values()) {
    ec2Client.configureRegion(region);

    // Find instances for region        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. However, I had to change it a bit:

```
for (Regions region : Regions.values()) { 
     ec2Client.setRegion(RegionUtils.getRegion(region.getName()));  

     DescribeInstancesResult describeInstances = c2Client.describeInstances();
...
```